# SSO with Okta as an SP

Tags: single-sign-on, service-provider, okta

I have an identity provider that connects to a service provider. Im trying to put Okta in the middle of the IDP and the service provider (so that Okta acts as an SP).

I got Okta to work directly with the SP. (I also got the IDP to work directly with the SP.) I'm having an issue getting the IDP to work with Okta in the middle.

Does the IDP's certificate go somewhere in Okta in this case? Does the SP need any information about the IDP?

Is it possible that I have admin access but couldnt find the add identity provider option in Okta?

Answer (score 0):

Would be curious to know what your use case is.

If you put Okta in the middle - then Okta is part SP (to your IDP) and part IDP (to your ultimate SP).

For the part where Okta is SP - you can leverage the instructions here - https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/40561903-Configuring-Inbound-SAML to set up an inbound SAML endpoint.

For the second part - to integrate Okta to your SP, you can use the instructions here to set up a SAML app via our App Wizard - https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Using-the-App-Integration-Wizard

If your SP happens to be in our app catalogue, then you can simply do "add application" under the Application tab in the admin console and follow the instructions there to set up SAML with the app.

Comment: Please see the revised question